# 50 champion generator plugged into a Generlink 40 Amp Meter Mounted Transfer Switch

Tags: generator

Hello and thanks in advance, I would like to buy the Generlink 40 Amp Meter Mounted Transfer Switch but my champion generator puts out 50 amps.  Will this overload the switch.  I know it will only let 40amps into my panel and I'm fine with that.  i just don't want to overload anything.  Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How do you know that it will only let 40A into the panel; does it have its own breaker?

Comment: GenerLink
40 Amp Meter Mounted Transfer Switch with 75kA Per Phase Surge Protection

Comment: this is the model number MA24-S

Comment: Is there a reason you are going for a meter-mounted transfer switch configuration, instead of something more integrated into your house's electrical system?

Comment: Wow, a generator-industry-supplied transfer switch *that actually makes sense*.  The wiring is simplicity itself. Much as I'm in love with the $23 Siemens transfer switch, this one is a real ATS with onboard overcurrent protection.

Comment: @Harper -- the issue with meter-mounted transfer switches is that some utilities don't like them

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I can understand that. The physical connection provided by a meter pan seems fit for meters, and too weak for something where people will be manhandling NEMA -50 connectors in and out.  Hopefully they are the L twistlocks, which have much lower insertion force.  But, shrug, UL listed the things, didn't they?  Didn't they?

Comment: @Harper -- they are NRTL listed, yes

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't appear to be a problem.  Supposedly, UL approved the instructions along with the device, and the instructions plainly invite you to plug in any generator with a compatible socket.

The instructions state the meter device has internal overload sensing/protection, and if your generator delivers more than 40A (because you drew that much), it will automatically disconnect the generator for you.

This doesn't even require any extra hardware; presumably if you overload the generator, it simply throws the transfer switch to utility power (which is dead, obviously).  Rather clever.